# Changing class from 'character' to other type which supports rowSums in r

Tags: r

I have a matrix with: character class entries.

```
sapply(mat,class)
"character"
```

I would like to apply rowSums to this matrix but I get the error:

```
Error in rowSums(mat) : 'x' must be numeric
```

If I do as.numeric(mat) then I get a vector.

Is there a way to change from character to numeric but keep the matrix structure?

Comment: Storing numbers as strings is overall asking for trouble; you should do the conversion during (or just after) loading your data.

Comment: mbq: is integer a good way of storing numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could change the storage mode of your matrix:

```
mmat <- matrix(c("2","3","7","0"), ncol = 2)
storage.mode(mmat) <- "double"  # changed from "numeric"
rowSums(mmat)
# [1] 9 3
```

Comment: what's the difference between double and numeric?

Comment: @user1723765, briefly, `double` is a valid R internal storage type, whereas `numeric` is a class of object that can be either a `double` or an `integer`. See `?storage.mode`, `?typeof`, `?double` and `?numeric` for a bit more info. Here, I don't think there should be a difference.